# Read file from Springboot Resources in Docker Container

Tags: spring-boot, jar, dockerfile

I am trying to send email with inline image in the email body. The code is working fine when I am running it locally from eclipse. But when it's getting dockerized and deployed to Kubernetes cluster it's unable to read the png file.

I am getting the error "java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [External_Files/email_template.png] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/External_Files/email_template.png"
[Project structure screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1X1t.png)

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
message.setSubject(AppConstants.EMAIL_SUBJECT);
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart(AppConstants.RELATED);
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
String html = AppConstants.EMAIL_HTML_PART_1 + recepientName + 
AppConstants.EMAIL_HTML_PART_2
    + fromName + AppConstants.EMAIL_HTML_PART_3 + appProperties.getEmailOnboardPage()
    + AppConstants.EMAIL_HTML_PART_4 + appProperties.getEmailHelpPage()
    + AppConstants.EMAIL_HTML_PART_5;
messageBodyPart.setContent(html, AppConstants.TEXT_HTML);
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(ResourceUtils.getFile(src/main/resources/External_Files/email_template.png));
 messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
 messageBodyPart2.setHeader(AppConstants.CONTENT_ID, AppConstants.IMAGE_HEADER);
 multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);

 message.setContent(multipart);
message.setHeader(AppConstants.X_PRIORITY, AppConstants.ONE);
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient));
log.info("executing Transport.send");
Transport.send(message);
```

[png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5wgO.png)

Answer (score 0):

@Indranil Halder I know it's late to answer but for others who have this problem finding this issue would be useful

you can use ResourceLoader to find classpath in spring jar file

```
@Autowired
ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:External_Files/email_template.png");
```